# How to set DataContext from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

if i try to set my `DataContext` via `Button_Click` the child doesn't get it inherited. What do i miss here?

Simple Test example:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Datacontext"
            Height="50" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ContentControl Name="Test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test.DataContext = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

**Result**

The `ContentPresenter` which is generated in the `ContentControl` is after the click still null but should be `DateTime`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DataContext for the Content**Control** is set, you are inspecting the Content**Presenter** *within* the ContentControl...

```
<ContentControl Name="Test" Content="{Binding}">
```

will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `ContentControl.DataContext` which `Content` is `null`.

Try setting actual content first, e.g.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Test">
    <!-- this will have DataContext as you expected -->
    <TextBlock />
</ContentControl>
```